# multimensional array find values

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have the following:

```
A=[2,3,4]

A(:,:,1) =
    0.9572    0    1 
    0    0.1419    0.9157
A(:,:,2) =
    0     0.9575    0
    0.5469    1    0.9706
...
```

I want to find B with the values between 0 and 1, for each column of the matrix A, and for each 5 slices.

From `A(:,:,1)` I would get:

```
0.9572 0.1419 0.9157
```

from `A(:,:,2)` I would get:

```
0.5469 0.9575 0.9706
```

At the end matrix B would be B(1,3,4).

Any suggestions to do this?

thanks

Comment: So you want elements different from 0 and 1 in each slice? Is the number of such elements the same in all slices?

Comment: yes, I want to write the elements between 0 and 1 in each column(I will have 3 columns), for each slice (I will get 4 slices).

Comment: the number of elements is the same in all slices

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
s = size(A, 3);                         %// number of slices
B = reshape(A, [], s);                  %// collapse first two dimensions into one
ind = (B>0) & (B<1);                    %// logical index of desired values
result = B(ind);                        %// index into B. Gives a column vector
result = reshape(result, 1, [], s);     %// reshape into desired form
```

Comment: well, I was wrong: the number of values (between 0 and 1) can change from column to column, so I can not collapse it....

Answer (score 0):

The number of values not being the same for each slice, you'll have to work with cell arrays:

```
B = cellfun(@(values) values(0 < values & values < 1),... %// Take values between 0 and 1 for each slice
            squeeze(num2cell(A, [1 2])),...               %// To cell array, each slice into a cell
            'UniformOutput', false);                      %// Output is (and has to be) a cell array
B{1} %// 0.9572 0.1419 0.9157 
B{2} %// 0.5469 0.9575 0.9706
```